# boolean var returning undefined after calling that variable form different component

Tags: angular

There are 2 components i.e header and login.
If the value of loginU returns true then I want to show logout button in header comp. In console its showing boolean as undefined in header comp.

login comp.ts:

```
  public isloggedin: boolean;

  loginU(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    const username = e.target.elements[0].value;
    const password = e.target.elements[1].value;
    console.log(username, password);


    if (username === 'admin' && password === 'admin') {
      console.log(e);
      this.isloggedin = true;
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      return this.isloggedin
    } else {
      this.loginStatus = 'Invalid Username/Password';

    }
  }
```

header comp:

```
import {LoginComponent} from '../login/login.component';

constructor private _login: LoginComponent) { 

ngOnInit() {
   console.log("From header " +  this._login.isloggedin)
}
```

header.component.html:

```
      <button *ngIf="_login.isloggedin" mat-button (click)="logout()" style="outline:none;margin-left: 5px;float: right;">

 </button>
```

Comment: You need to have `login.component` as a `ViewChild` inside your `headerComponent`, or you can use `BehaviorSubject` to achieve that communication. Or, since a login stuff, you can use `AuthGuard`

Comment: I just went throught ViewChild in documentation. I'm not understanding.Do I need to have some other basics for that

Comment: I can show you a sample code, just tell me if both of `header` and `login` are part of the same `html` or, for some reasons, `header` is a component inside the `login` component in html. You can simply add the main `.html` to your question

Comment: header and login are both differnent html code. Login will contain form and header will contain logout button.

Comment: @kedarkulk you need to read that guide, from top to bottom. You're not using Angular the right way. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Oh! So.. I need to use Input()  to pass the values from one component to another.

Comment: You can use `@Input` or share the resources with a service or using an event emitter

Comment: is loginComponent  included in the  header.component.html:?

Comment: If the login is successful then you can store the data in the `localstorage` and then in app component create a function that check if the `localstorage` is empty or not, and based on the observation returns true and false and use that value to render the header component using `*ngIf=ifLogin()` something like that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Doing it using BehaviorSubject**

Let's pretend we have the `main-container.html` like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <header-component></header-component>
  <login-component></login-component>
</div>
```

login.service.ts

```
export class LoginService{
  private isLogged$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
  public isLoggedEvent = this.isLogged$.asObservable();

  public setUserLogged(status: boolean){
    this.isLogged$.next(status);
  }
}
```

login.component.ts

```
   //your other stuff

constructor(
  private service: LoginService
) { }
    loginU(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);
        const username = e.target.elements[0].value;
        const password = e.target.elements[1].value;
        console.log(username, password);


        if (username === 'admin' && password === 'admin') {
          console.log(e);
          this.service.setUserLogged(true);
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
          return this.isloggedin
        } else {
          this.loginStatus = 'Invalid Username/Password';

        }
      }

header.component.ts

    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit{

      public isLogged = false;

      constructor(
        private service: LoginService
      ) { }

      ngOnInit: void {
        this.service.isLoggedEvent
        .subscribe( isLogged => {
          this.isLogged = isLogged;
        });
      }

  logout(){
    //your logout stuff
    this.service.setUserLogged(false);
  }
```

}

header.component.html

```
 <button *ngIf="isLogged" mat-button (click)="logout()" style="outline:none;margin-left: 5px;float: right;">
 </button> 
 <div *ngIf="!isLogged">User is not logged in</div>
```

Acting this way, your header component will update itSelf whenever the state of `isLogged$` change. If you want to use `@Input` on the `login.component` just tell me and I will edit this answer showing you how do it aswell.

Comment: It should be capital B in  behaviorSubject I guess

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which relationship your components have, Parent/Child/Sibling,  you can use one of the following way to share your `boolean` value :

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/