# How to pass angular2/4 parameter in single page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular4-forms, angular4-router

I have an interface in which interface I get a popup search tab with an editable list.

But I am not aware of the method to get data to the main interface for edit after I click this list edit button.

Simply what I need is to pass the id of the current item to main edit view as a parameter.if any body can help me

**My code:**

[image]

**This is my TS file:**

```
Editmodeclose(value: any) {
    let ItemID: number = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['code'];

    alert(this.userid);
    alert(this.shopid);
    alert(this.ItemID); //(here item id show undefined)
    this._enqService.FetchStockitem(ItemID, this.shopid, this.userid)
      .subscribe(
        defaultdatas => this.defaultdata = defaultdatas,
        error => {
          console.error(error);
          this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
      });
    $("#SearchModal").modal("hide");
}
```

My html

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 text-right">
  <span class="btn btn-success Editmode-Btn" (click)="Editmodeclose()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
</div>
</div>
<ng-container *ngFor="let items of defaultdata;">
  <a [routerLink]="['/NewStockCount',items.ItemID]">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Item Code</label>
          <span>{{items.ItemCode}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Item Description</label>

          <span>{{items.ItemDescription}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>(....etc.......)
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Are you seeing the URL changing in your address bar with the updated ID?

Comment: @SiddAjmera no i don't want to change the Url because these two functions are working on same page

Comment: use a `BehaviorSubject` to "connect" this two components

Comment: @JacopoSciampi how to use BehaviorSubject to this?actually i am new to this

Comment: You can use this logic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659520/boolean-var-returning-undefined-after-calling-that-variable-form-different-compo/52660039#52660039

Comment: for `BehaviorSubject` look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569073/want-to-show-more-data-in-another-component-when-view-in-detail-button-is-clicke/52569837#52569837

Answer (score 1):

You have made your list by using *ngFor directive when calling the method by clicking the button you are calling the method 'Editmodeclose()' just pass the 'item' or the reference variable which you have taken at the time of running loop in HTML like Editmodeclose(item), it will be going to call the method & pass the current clicking item(object) in to the method in component like

```
`Editmodeclose(item){console.log(item)};`
```

after that, you can assign this item to another variable 'data' & use this data variable to display data

Comment: i did not get the answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087795/angular-4-passing-a-value-from-html-template-to-a-method-in-a-component
just take the refrence of the url